# Crystal Reports cross tab but not with the "Cross-Tab" tool

Tags: crystal-reports

My question is simple. Is is possible to have a cross-tab-like table in crystal reports?
The rows are people, the columns are trainings and the data of the cells are dates that this person participated in the training..
Is this possible?
My first though was to have a formula with a Select/case to check the name o the training (because I don't care for all of them) and if the training name is Name1, the formula should set the date of the training to a variable and somehow I would be able to use this variable and show it to my report. But I don't know even if that is possible or how it could be done.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Question looks like create a crystal report without using crystal report tool...if you need dynamic columns you need cross tab...what is your exact requirement

Comment: I have been asked to create a table with the name of the participants for the rows, the names of the trainings for columns and each "cell" should be the date of training. Does that make sense?

Comment: does trainings that you are using for columns are static or dynamic?

Comment: Everything is static..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case since columns are static..you can try below process:

you can use the same design part or increase the design part till all the static columns fit the design using the `Page setup`.

manually create the columns and place side by side in header... either page or group as per your report requirement.

For rows place the fields that you want to see in details and make sure to provide sufficient space between Participates and Dates.

Now play a bit with lines between columns and rows so that it looks like table and add summaries as required.

This will give the display of the cross tab though it is not cross tab.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! :)